# Extension Method for List(Of Object) in VB

Tags: vb.net, list, methods

I have an extension method that works great in converting an object to my form object.

```
'Copy an object to a form object
<Extension()> _
Public Function FromModel(ToObject As BaseFormObject, ByRef FromObject As Object) As Boolean

    ToObject = FromObject

    Return True
End Function
```

I want to do the same thing for a list of objects.

```
'Copy a list of objects to form objects
<Extension()> _
Public Function FromModelList(ToList As List(Of BaseFormObject), ByRef FromList As List(Of Object)) As Boolean

    For Each FromItem As Object In FromList
        'Create a new BaseFormObject for every item in FromList, Add it to our From List
        Dim newFormObject = New BaseFormObject()
        newFormObject.FromModel(FromItem)
        ToList.Add(newFormObject)
    Next

    Return True
End Function
```

Creating a new List(Of BaseFormObject) does not give me access to the method "FromModelList."  What is the proper way to go about doing this?

Comment: Are you sure you have proper `Imports` added?

Comment: Import I am using is Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices, which works great for the first method.

Comment: Your code is so full of errors that I can't see how to help. You're passing `FromObject` by ref, but you don't need to do that. You're assigning an `Object` to `BaseFormObject` which you obviously can't always do. You then simply return `True`. Why? The second method is as bad. Is this just mock code for this question or are you using this as production code?

Comment: This is just mock code.  The Object to BaseFormObject is just a simple example of copying one object to another.   

The main question is how do I get a new instance of List(Of BaseFormObject) to have the FromModelList method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine.

I created this code:

```
    Dim lst As New List(Of BaseFormObject)
```

I got the extension member when I typed in `lst.`

I'm going to go out on a limb here and suggest that you're not actually instantiating a `List(Of BaseFormObject)`, but instead something like `List(Of ActualFormObject)` where `ActualFormObject` inherits from `BaseFormObject`.

So if I use this code:

```
    Dim lst As New List(Of ActualFormObject)
```

Then you don't get the extension member. If that's what you're hoping for, then it's easy to fix.

Change your code to this:

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function FromModelList(Of T As {New, BaseFormObject})(ToList As List(Of T), ByRef FromList As List(Of Object)) As Boolean
    For Each FromItem As Object In FromList
        'Create a new BaseFormObject for every item in FromList, Add it to our From List
        Dim newFormObject = New T()
        newFormObject.FromModel(FromItem)
        ToList.Add(newFormObject)
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

Then you get the extension member on lists of sub-classes.

Comment: This worked perfect.  Thank you for you help and patience.  I will try to explain my questions better in the future.